# Games with flipping tokens for action selection?

Tags: recommendations, mechanics

We are creating a game with what we think is a new action selection mechanic. The mechanic is based on poker chip like tokens that you flip to take the action the top side, then there is a different action on the bottom side. Have you encountered a similar mechanic in any other game?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Sadly I don't think its new.

I've seen flipping discs for action selection in various games such as [Mr Jack Pocket](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/72287/mr-jack-pocket).

There are also games that when actions are taken that a token or card is flipped and another action becomes available such as [Planet Defenders](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/204879/planet-defenders)

Another similar to what you described is [Coin Age](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/146130/coin-age) where the options you have are literally determined by the way coins land when flipped.

Comment: Cool to know I still think the mechanic we use is slightly different and definitely pretty innovative in a euro game. So I dont worry about that. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly tongue in cheek answer.

The Orchard Toys game [Dinosaur Race](https://www.orchardtoys.com/buy/dinosaur-race-board-game_58.htm) for 3 to 6 year olds uses a similar mechanic.
In this cases the double sided tokens are of dinosaurs performing different sports. After spinning the spinner, you move the number of spaces that there are tokens showing your sport, then flip the tokens over to the reverse. The next time that sport comes up, the number will be different.

As the tokens do not all have the same sports on the reverse the number of spaces you move each time a given sport comes up can vary substantially.